# Deleting HDF file if writing does not complete (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf

I am saving a Dataframe as an HDF file in Pandas, using:

```
store = pandas.HDFStore('myfile.h5', table=True)
store.append('df', df, chunksize=100000)
store.close()
```

I have this code in a Luigi pipeline, and it works fine - except when there is some error in the writing process (such as a mixed type column), such that `myfile.h5` appears on the drive but isn't fully written. Luigi thinks that task is complete, and then the next task fails because the `myfile.h5` isn't written fully.

How can I tell Python to delete `myfile.h5` if `store.append` doesn't fully complete?

Comment: use python's try-except?  (python's standard exception handling method)

Comment: @JohnE lol, I'm a moron. Yes, that would work - because `except` wouldn't write the file and then Luigi would notice the target output is missing, and then the task would fail. Thanks!

Comment: Not a moron I'm sure!   But we all sometimes forget we can drop back to python for things like this  ;-)

Comment: @JohnE, i think it's worth to write it as an answer - this might help someone in future

Comment: @maxu  OK, I'm pretty busy today but feel to write it up yourself if you like.